# rosdep install fails on yaml-cpp

Tags: ros, homebrew, rosdep-install, yaml-cpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the [ROS Indigo Install Guide](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source)

I'm currently on this command in a virtual environment:

```
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y
```

Which displays the following:

```
executing command [sudo -H pip install -U nose]
Password:
Collecting nose
  Using cached nose-1.3.7-py2-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: nose
Successfully installed nose-1.3.7
executing command [brew install yaml-cpp-0.3]
Warning: ros/deps/yaml-cpp-0.3-0.3.0 already installed, it's just not linked
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  homebrew: Failed to detect successful installation of [yaml-cpp-0.3]
```

I've been able to fix this before with `$ brew install --overwrite [package-name]` but I just get the same message as above:

```
$ brew install --overwrite yaml-cpp-0.3
Warning: ros/deps/yaml-cpp-0.3-0.3.0 already installed, it's just not linked
```

I tried overwriting `libyaml` and `yaml-cpp` as well with no resolve.

What should I try next?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222364/rosdep-install-fails-on-yaml-cpp/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2015-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to link `yaml-cpp-0.3`, as the warning suggests. You can do so with:

```
$ brew link yaml-cpp-0.3
```

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1